# Updating a table description in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to update the description of a table this way

`bq update --description "${description_text}" ${project_id}:${dataset_name}.${table_name}`

However when the `description_text` is multi line, it fails with the error `Invalid header value`
My goal is to update the description a table with the SQL statement that it was created
So am doing it programmatically to each time pick up a SQL file from a location, create the table and update the description from the contents of the SQL. That way, I know how that table was created

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
description_text="this is line one
this is line two
this is line three"

bq update --description "${description_text}" ${project_id}:${dataset_name}.${table_name}
```

Comment: This does not work when there are multiline description text. Is this a SDK version issue

Comment: Tagging @Mikhail

Answer (score 0):

Certain installations of the `bq` command line tool are unable to process multiline inputs. Notably, the Google Cloud Shell is currently broken for me. (`bq` works fine in a fresh Compute Engine VM, and on my MacBook.)

You can work around this by using echo. For example

```
bq query 'select
5'
```

throws an error, but this works:

```
echo 'select
5' | bq query --nouse_legacy_sql
```